How to isolate environment variables from the shared lambda function template in cloudformation
This is my function.yaml which creates the lambda function here I have put the environment variables but it's shared all across the lambda function stack I make function.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Event Lambda function

Parameters:
  # Existing parameters...
  ENVVAR1:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 1
    Default: 'value1'
  ENVVAR2:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 2
    Default: 'value2'
  ENVVAR3:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 3
    Default: 'value3'
  ENVVAR4:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 4
    Default: 'value4'

Resources:
  LambdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - !Ref LayerRuntimePython
      Content:
        S3Bucket: !Ref LayerS3BucketName
        S3Key: !Ref LayerS3Key
        S3ObjectVersion: !Ref LayerS3ObjectVersion
      Description: !Ref LayerDescription
      LayerName: !Ref LayerName
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ### lambda function permissions

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunctionName
      Handler: !Ref HandlerFunction
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref S3CodeBucket
        S3Key: !Ref S3CodeBucketKey
        S3ObjectVersion: !Ref CodeS3ObjectVersion
      Runtime: !Ref LayerRuntimePython
      Timeout: !Ref LambdaExecutionTimeout
      MemorySize: !Ref LambdaMemorySize
      Layers:
        - !Ref LambdaLayer
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ENVVAR1: !Ref ENVVAR1
          ENVAR2: !Ref ENVVAR2
          ENVVAR3: !Ref ENVVAR3
          ENVVAR4: !Ref ENVVAR4

Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: ARN of the Lambda function
    Value: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-LambdaFunctionArn"
  LambdaFunctionName:
    Description: Name of the Lambda function
    Value: !Ref LambdaFunctionName

And my dev.yaml looklike this
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AWS EC2 Backup Policy for Production Environment

Parameters:
  Function1CodeS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 object version of the OOOCalendarSync code.
    Default: '1'
  GoogleLayerS3:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 object version of the Google Layer.
    Default: '1'
  Function2CodeS3Version:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 object version of the Auto MSCK Lambda function code.
    Default: '1'
  

Resources:
  MyFunction1:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: common/lambda/function.yaml
      Parameters:
        LayerS3BucketName: layer-aws-s3-bucket
        LayerS3Key: google-layer.zip
        LayerName: "google-layer"
        LayerDescription: "Layer for Common Function"
        LayerRuntimePython: "python3.12"
        S3CodeBucket: my-s3-aws-lambda-code-bucket
        S3CodeBucketKey: function1.zip
        LambdaExecutionTimeout: 300
        LambdaMemorySize: 256
        HandlerFunction: "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
        LayerS3ObjectVersion: !Ref GoogleLayerS3
        CodeS3ObjectVersion: !Ref Function1CodeS3Version
        LambdaFunctionName: 'ooo_calendar_sync-dev'
        ENVVAR1: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:env/lambda:SecretString:MYVAR1}}'
        ENVVAR2: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:env/lambda:SecretString:MYVAR2}}'

  MyFunction2:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: common/lambda/function.yaml
      Parameters:
        LayerS3BucketName: layer-aws-s3-bucket
        LayerS3Key: google-layer.zip
        LayerName: "google-layer"
        LayerDescription: "Layer for Common Function"
        LayerRuntimePython: "python3.12"
        S3CodeBucket: my-s3-aws-lambda-code-bucket
        S3CodeBucketKey: function2.zip
        LambdaExecutionTimeout: 300
        LambdaMemorySize: 256
        HandlerFunction: "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
        LayerS3ObjectVersion: !Ref GoogleLayerS3
        CodeS3ObjectVersion: !Ref Function2CodeS3Version
        LambdaFunctionName: 'auto_msck-dev'
        ENVVAR3: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:env/lambda:SecretString:MYVAR3}}'
        ENVVAR4: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:env/lambda:SecretString:MYVAR4}}'


But the ENVVAR1 and ENVVAR2 is appearing in MyFunction2 and same for MyFunction1 for ENVVAR3 and ENVVAR4 I don't want to be shared across other function. I tried referencing following link but I am kinda lost over here. Dynamic environment variables for AWS Lambda using cloudformation template. Please help and please mind suggesting if there is any mistakes.

Fixed and done using the conditions and if conditions in function.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Event Lambda function

Parameters:
  ENVVAR1:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 1
    Default: ""

  ENVVAR2:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 2
    Default: ""

  ENVVAR3:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 3
    Default: ""

  ENVVAR4:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment variable 4
    Default: ""
  
  S3CodeBucket:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 bucket name for the Lambda function code
  LambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the Lambda function
  S3CodeBucketKey:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 key for the Lambda function code
  CodeS3ObjectVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 object version of the Lambda function code
  LambdaExecutionTimeout:
    Type: Number
    Description: Timeout for the Lambda function
  LambdaMemorySize:
    Type: Number
    Description: Memory size for the Lambda function
  HandlerFunction:
    Type: String
    Description: Handler function for the Lambda function
  LayerS3BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 bucket name for the Lambda layer
  LayerS3Key:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 key for the Lambda layer
  LayerS3ObjectVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 object version of the Lambda layer
  LayerName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the Lambda layer
  LayerDescription:
    Type: String
    Description: Description of the Lambda layer
  LayerRuntimePython:
    Type: String
    Description: Python runtime for the Lambda layer

  

Conditions:
  ENVVALUE1: !Not [!Equals [!Ref ENVVAR1, ""]]
  ENVVALUE2: !Not [!Equals [!Ref ENVVAR2, ""]]
  ENVVALUE3: !Not [!Equals [!Ref ENVVAR3, ""]]
  ENVVALUE4: !Not [!Equals [!Ref ENVVAR4, ""]]

Resources:
  LambdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - !Ref LayerRuntimePython
      Content:
        S3Bucket: !Ref LayerS3BucketName
        S3Key: !Ref LayerS3Key
        S3ObjectVersion: !Ref LayerS3ObjectVersion
      Description: !Ref LayerDescription
      LayerName: !Ref LayerName

  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AppendToLogsPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: "*"

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunctionName
      Handler: !Ref HandlerFunction
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref S3CodeBucket
        S3Key: !Ref S3CodeBucketKey
        S3ObjectVersion: !Ref CodeS3ObjectVersion
      Runtime: !Ref LayerRuntimePython
      Timeout: !Ref LambdaExecutionTimeout
      MemorySize: !Ref LambdaMemorySize
      Layers:
        - !Ref LambdaLayer
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ENVVAR1: !If [ENVVALUE1, !Ref ENVVAR1, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
          ENVVAR2: !If [ENVVALUE2, !Ref ENVVAR2, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
          ENVVAR3: !If [ENVVALUE3, !Ref ENVVAR3, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
          ENVVAR4: !If [ENVVALUE4, !Ref ENVVAR4, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]

Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: ARN of the Lambda function
    Value: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-LambdaFunctionArn"
  LambdaFunctionName:
    Description: Name of the Lambda function
    Value: !Ref LambdaFunctionName


